# Can you use backup of one machine on a different machine?

Tags: installation, backup

I don't have fancy directory seperation. I have a desktop and laptop, and for the last few months I did a lot of work on my laptop. I don't want to waste my time installing and configuring on my desktop.

Can I use the laptop's backup on the Desktop?

I know the potential concerns are drivers. How can I deal with such issue?
(Both are Ubuntu 11.04)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not install any drivers outside of the Ubuntu repositories (nvidia, ati, wireless) you should be just fine.

If you did you would need to re-install them.

Another possibility would be to generate a list of installed packages and us it for a fresh install

[old install]

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections > packages.list
```

Now put them back on the new installation

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections <packages
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Then copy your data or other files in $HOME, perhaps on a flash drive.

Comment: While this is a good way of cloning a baseline package set, it doesn't include any customisation.

Comment: What customization do you want ? User customization is in $HOME.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't install any drivers myself. I will give you a check when I done with the installation. Thanks.