# why can we backup from one machine and restore to another different machine using tar?

Tags: backup, restore

i know the 2 method of backup from one machine and restore to another diffrent machine.

1. using tar all of the file you have in system rooted at /

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087

2. package backup and restore & backup all of the config and home file

[Can you use backup of one machine on a different machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94779/can-you-use-backup-of-one-machine-on-a-different-machine)

i think 1 is the easy and best way (cause when you do 2 method, there is some warning in dpkg(sudo dpkg --set-selections < backupfile), and install exactly same packages is really hard), but someone says it may not support specific h/w so it's a little bit dangerous. 
but when you compile kernel by built-in default config (i mean /arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig) there is only one config and i think it mean x86 support backward compatibility in linux. so 1 method is okay for different machine. 
is it really dangerous to use 1 method i mentioned ?

Comment: The Ubuntuforums link you included seems to have nothing to do with `tar` or backing up your system...?

Comment: sorry, i corrected that....

Comment: I can't answer your question about the `tar` method but I would recommend using a professional (but free) tool like the Clonezilla boot CD for making backup images or clones of partitions or whole disks.

Comment: Are you trying to do a backup or explaining how one should do one?

Comment: i used both of them, and they worked correctly. i just want to know which method is better?